# Can't merge free disk space using disk management in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

I have 40 GB of un-allocated free disk space and I can't merge this free space to any of my default drives. Screenshots included below. Any help is appreciated!

[image: http://imgur.com/a/H57RN]

[image: ttp://imgur.com/a/H57RN]

[image: ttp://imgur.com/a/H57RN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few months ago. I would recommend a software called  AOMEI Partition Assistant 6.3 that worked just fine for me. [You can download it here!](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html)

Best Regards,

Alessandro Z.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right... windows doesn't like you have more than 3 primary partitions on a fixed disk. It looks like the partition you are trying to extend is a logical partition. I believe you can use another tool as mentioned in the 1st response to your question. The other thing that I do (Not sure that it matters but I do it anyway), is make the system reserved partition 500MB