# how to make a partition and the hard drive seen by a linux distribution (dell inspiron 14)

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning

I've resized my main partition on a Windows 10. The Pc is a Dell Inspiron 14.

I've used `diskmgmt.msc`

So far, so good as you can on the picture below

[image]

There is a free space, 224Gb almost, `non-alloué` means non allocated.

However, as you can see, everything is on `Disque 0` meaning `Disk 0`. When I'm trying to install a linux distribution, the linux distribution does not see any free space, worse it does not see the disk.

My aim is to have Linux see that free space and start the install.

**Update 1**

---

After some talks in the comments, please find the screencaptures I did. No other partitions are showing up, except my usb key seen as `sda`.

With the `lsblk`

[image]

And now [image]the `fdisk`

[image]

[image]

I did a `fidsk -l` and here is the result

[image]

**Update 2**

---

As asked, please find the screencapture of my controller

[image]

Comment: The point of view of Linux (or Linux installer) will be useful. Can you get to a console and run `lsblk`, `gdisk -l /dev/sdx` (or `fdisk -l /dev/sdx`)? (replace `x` with the right letter: `a`, `b` or so). Use `sudo` if needed. Please [edit] and post the output. Alternatively a screenshot (or a photo) of the installer when it shows you the disk(s). The latter may not bring much data, but it's a start.

Comment: Hi @KamilMaciorowski, not sure. I've tried to start a console but nothing is appearing. From the Pop OS's perspective, it only shows my  usb key. I'll take a picture after my meeting.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, please have a look when you can.

Comment: I guess the Linux installer misses a driver proper for whatever controller you connect the disk to. How is the disk connected?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it is locked inside of the computer. As it is a brand new one, I'm not willing to open it up right now with the screw drivers and etc.

Comment: So tell M. Maciorowski *what Windows says* about how the disk is connected.  Open up Disk Management and pick the Disk List.  Open up Device Manager and pick the by connection view.

Comment: hi @JdeBP, let's stay courteous or as much as possible ;) Do you have any ideas, please?

Comment: Linux doesn't see the disk because it's lacking drivers for the controller. We need info what kind of controller your system is using. Please check Device Manager in Windows.

Comment: hi @gronostaj, please find the update on my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tryouts, I found out what was causing the issue.

It was due to an option in the bios called `Rapid Storage Technology`. That option when activated was preventing the hard drive to be seen by the linux distribution.

I found out that, when I tried to install another linux distribution, Ubuntu.

Ubuntu gave me the correct diagnostic.

After the deactivation of the option, the hard drive is now seen by the distribution.

Comment: Does the solution affect Windows in a significant way? What are your observations? Answer upvoted anyway. Well done.

Answer (score -2):

Your disk is most likely formatted as
[master boot record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record),
since it's not large enough to require
[GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).

MBR can handle at most 4 primary partitions, so you have reached the
maximum number of primary partitions that are possible for MBR.

For adding one more partition, you will need to delete one of the existing
partitions, in order to make room for the new installation.

I would guess that the space you have made available is inside an extended
partition, so is not seen by the Linux installation.

Comment: -1. The screenshot shows 5 primary partitions already.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Most likely there are actually 3 primary and one extended partition containing the nested logical drives that you're seeing. This explanation fits both the image and poster's experience.

Comment: There's no extended partition visible on the screenshot, though.

Comment: No. Near the bottom of the screenshot there is a description, color mapping. There is "unallocated" and "primary partition" there. For "extended partition" and "logical drive" Windows uses different colors and the terms appear in the description if needed. Compare the screenshots [here](https://superuser.com/q/1231237/432690).

Comment: hi @harrymc, thank you for your comment. As Kamil asked, I've took some screen captures. Please have a look on my post.

Comment: @AndyK: It's up to you to say if you have an extended partition or not, because this explains why Linux can't see the space. If not, then a question: It's not possible that, as this is just unallocated space and not a real partition, that this is the reason that you would think that Linux doesn't see it? In this case, just give it `/dev/sda/` and it should use the unallocated space and create the partition, or you can create it yourself.

Comment: @gronost, you are right!  I don't know where I remember seeing this happen but "back in the day" before GPT.. someone figured out how to do it.  I will remove my stupid comment.. until I figure out more.  Thanks for correcting me! (I mean it!)